# How Serilog posts to CloudWatch without any configuration setup?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, aws-lambda, serilog

I am migrating an app done in net core from Azure to AWS. Backend is an Asp.NetCore WebApi which uses Serilog for logging. 
I simply put it behind a subclass of Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction and now it runs in a lambda function. What perplexes me is how the logs generated with Serilog go to Cloudwatch of this deployed lambda function automatically. Can someone explain how these logging libraries work that perhaps the logging entities in Lambda nuget package can automatically tap on to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, everything that you write to the `Console` from within an AWS Lambda function, ends up in AWS CloudWatch, so if you are writing to the Console via [Serilog.Sinks.Console](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console), that's why...

ps: You might also be interested in using Amazon's officially supported Serilog sink [`AWS.Logger.SeriLog`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWS.Logger.SeriLog/)

Comment: Thank you very much for shedding light on this. I see Serilog.AspNetCore and Serilog.Sinks.Console in the nuget libraries in the VS project I am working on (I am not the original developer). In the code I see a static class under Serilog namespace is used to write logs. Can I just conclude Serilog.Sinks.Console is behind the scenes writing to Console and that is how logs propagate to CloudWatch?

Comment: You're welcome. The static class under the Serilog namespace is the class that will write the messages to **all** of the sinks configured (`Serilog.Sinks.Console` might be one of many, or might be the only one... It all depends on how Serilog is configured in the app). Look inside of your `LambdaEntryPoint` and `Program` classes and you'll probably find the Serilog configuration pipeline. You might want to search for `LoggerConfiguration` and `UseSerilog` also. Your appsettings.config might also have Serilog sinks configured there...

Comment: You can look at the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---) also take a look at these [examples](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/tree/dev/samples) on how to configure Serilog in ASP .NET Core to know what to look for and where, in your app.